# Working with time in calculate columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I am working in a calculate column that should calculate the time minus x minutes based on another date-time column.

I have a start date column of type date-time and I need calculate that time minus x minutes in the calculate column. Now the tryck is that the user will insert the amount of minutes in another column.

So the list looks like this:

```
StartTime                AmountOfMinutes           EndDate (calculated column)
2019-03-28 09:00:00          10                    2019-03-28 08:50:00
```

I found a formula that extract 15 minutes and it looks like this:

```
=[StartTime]-(1/24/4)
```

The 4 in the formula represent 15 minutes. I need to use the user inserted time instead the 4 in the forumla. Or find some another way. 
After that a Flow will get trigged at the EndDate time. (MS Flow).

How can I use the user selected amount of minutes in the formula?

Best regards
Americo

Comment: Hi Americo, did below answer helped?

Comment: Yes, see my comment down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create formula like this:

```
=StartTime-(AmountOfMinutes/1440)
```

1440 is number of minutes in a day. I just tested this in my environment and it worked.

For reference: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/05/calculated-columns-adding-hours-onto-a-date-field/

Comment: A more user intuitive way may be ‘=StartTime-minutes/60/24’ to know a bit more on where the 1440 is coming from

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot mark the answer. Yes it worked. Thanks a lot